# Word Replacement in text corpus using word2vec similarity dictionary in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching, word2vec, gensim

I have created a word2vec  dictionary using Gensim .I want replace my text corpus with the root word .
Is there a way by which we can replace the text data corpus by the root word .

**Eg. Building is my root word and i have similarity of it in my dictionary. I want replace all similar words to building that have similarity above.6 in my orginal text corpus**.

**Sample data from column of the dataframe**

```
canara bank aon china bldng queens rd centeal central
des voeux rd west hk unit f kwan yick bldng phase central western
formula growth asia limited suite chinachem tower connaught rd central
bangkok bank public company limited central district branch des voeux rd central cenrta
```

**Similarities**

```
  model.most_similar("building")
    [('bu', 0.762892484664917),
     ('bldg', 0.7351159453392029),
     ('bl', 0.7237456440925598),
     ('building.', 0.7153196334838867),
     ('buliding', 0.6988817453384399),
     ('bld', 0.6966143846511841),
     ('bldng', 0.663501501083374),
     ('bdg', 0.6504702568054199),
     ('bd', 0.6480772495269775),
     ('blog', 0.6432161331176758)]

model.most_similar("ltd")
[('limited', 0.7886955142021179),
 ('limi', 0.6512018442153931),
 ('limite', 0.6031635999679565),
 ('wilford', 0.5938706994056702),
 ('lt', 0.583463728427887),
 ('lighttech', 0.5828145146369934),
 ('rmc', 0.5821658372879028),
 ('tomoike', 0.5752800703048706),
 ('jd', 0.5751883387565613),
 ('nxp', 0.5725069046020508)]
```

**Dictionary**

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora,similarities,models
class AccCorpus(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ''


    def __iter__(self):
        for sentence in data["Adj_Addr"]:
            yield [word.lower() for word in sentence.split()]


def build_corpus():
    model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025,window=2,sg=2)
    sentences = AccCorpus()
    model.build_vocab(sentences)
    for epoch in range(1):
        model.train(sentences,total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
        model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
        model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay

    model_name = "word2vec_model"
    model.save(model_name)
    return model
model=build_corpus()
```

Comment: That depends on what format your corpus starts in, and what format you want it to end in - and that's not really a `gensim` or `word-embedding` problem, just Python string manipulation. Separately: by setting `min_alpha` the same as `alpha`, you're not doing typical stochastic-gradient-descent in your training. You might get better results leaving `min_alpha` at its default.

Comment: @gojomo, My data is address data column inside  adataframe`(data["Adj_Addr"])`. Can you demonstrate how to do that using example. I am not sure how based on similarity we will replace words in the corpus. I have updated  sample of my data corpus in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Gensim does not offer functionality to do this.

My answer relies on a few heavy assumptions, but here it goes.

**Assumptions:**

1. You have a list of pre-defined root words in a variable called `root_words`. Given your example above, this would look like `root_words = ["building", "ltd", ...]`
2. Your text data is formatted as a list of tokens in your dataframe `data` i.e. one row of `data["Adj_Addr"]` may look like ['bldg', 'wilford', 'bld'] for example

/

```
threshold = 0.6 # define a threshold
similar_words = {word:{} for word in root_words} # create a dictionary from root_words
for word in root_words:
    """        
    Loop over all words in root_words and create
    a temp dict with values above the threshold using the
    model.most_similar() method
    """
    temp_dict = dict(model.most_similar(word))
    temp_dict = {k:v for k,v in temp_dict.items() if v > threshold}
    # append the temp dict to the similar_words dict
    similar_words[word] = temp_dict


def replace_words(text):
    """
    1.Loop over every word in the text (text is one row in the data 
    2.If the word is in root_words, simply append it to temp_text
    3.If not, then loop over all words in the similar_words dict, and
    check if the current word is in one of the sub dictionaries - if so,
    append the root_word to the temp_text
    4. Use the flags so we don't miss out on any words (e.g. there
    may be words that are not in the root_words list or in the
    similar_words sub dictionaries
    5. Return temp_text
    """
    temp_text = []
    for word in text:
        in_root_words_flag = False
        found_root_flag = False

        if word in root_words:
            temp_text.append(word)
            in_root_words_flag = True

        else:
            for root_word in similar_words:
                if word in similar_words[root_word]:
                    temp_text.append(root_word)
                    found_root_flag = True

        if in_root_words_flag == False and found_root_flag == False:
            temp_text.append(word)

    return temp_text

# apply the function above to your text data and create a new column
data['replaced_words'] = data["Adj_Addr"].apply(replace_words)
```

Granted, the method is a bit convoluted, relies on assumptions and is for loop intensive (inefficient). But it should work.